# How to set a margin-top of the size of the windows?

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to put a `div` with CSS just after the current window (i.e when you start scrolling you see it).

It seems trivial and I tried

```
#content {
    margin-top: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z74dx/)

But It isn't working and the  margin don't take the height the current window.

Comment: I checked the jsfiddle and it works perfectly for me. As soon as I started to scroll I see the lorem ipsum. Where do you start to see the text ?

Comment: What about increasing the `margin` size?  `margin-top: 120%;` http://jsfiddle.net/Z74dx/

Comment: @Alex have you solved your issue or do you need more assistance? did my answer fullfill your requirements? If yes, please tick it accepted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solutions :**

1. You can achieve your aim using `position:absolute;` and `top:100%;`
   **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Z74dx/3/)**
2. second option is to add an element with `height:100%;` to "push" `.content` down 
   **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Z74dx/9/)**

**Explanation :**

The issue is that percent `margin-top` (like `margin-bottom` or `padding-top/bottom`) is **calculated according to parent's width**. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top)

> Percentages refer to the width of the containing block

**CSS :**

```
body,html {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}

#content {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

**Code option 2 :**

HTML :

```
<div id="push"></div>
<div id="content">
    <p>... content ...</p>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body,html {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#push{
    height:100%;
}

#content {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: +1 I wonder why they decided to base it on the container's width than height, which is logical for top and bottom margins.

Comment: @Alex Updated my answer with a second option : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Z74dx/9/